# I used "data-target" to keep the active link style. How to maintain style even when moving pages from an active link

Tags: javascript, html, css

Referring to the answer of another question, I wrote the code to preserve the style when the link is activated using "data-target".
But the style disappears when moving to the next page in the active link.
For example, if the original link is "link/sub01.html" but changes to "link/sub01.html&page=2", the style is lost.
I want the style to be maintained whenever there is a "data-target" value in the link.
But I'm not familiar with the script yet, so I don't know where to fix it.
Please help me.

I didn't speak English, so I used a translator.
So the sentence may not be smooth.
Sorry!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location;
    $('.mainCateBox li a[href="' + 'data-target' + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('.mainCateBox li a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .mainCateBox {
        position: relative;
    }

    .mainCateBox:after {
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }

    .mainCateBox li {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 180px;
        height: 34px;
        float: left;
        line-height: 34px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .mainCateBox li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .mainCateBox li:hover {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .mainCateBox li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .mainCateBox li.active {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .mainCateBox li.active a {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>


<div id="prdListCate">
    <ul class="mainCateBox">
        <li data-target="index"><a href="index.html">MAIN</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub01"><a href="sub01.html">SUB01</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub02"><a href="sub02.html">SUB02</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

slator.
So the sentence may not be smooth.
Sorry..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used index of to check the url is there at the start of the string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location;
    $('.mainCateBox li a[href="' + 'data-target' + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('.mainCateBox li a').filter(function() {
        return (this.href.indexOf(url) === 0)
    }).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .mainCateBox {
        position: relative;
    }

    .mainCateBox:after {
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }

    .mainCateBox li {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 180px;
        height: 34px;
        float: left;
        line-height: 34px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .mainCateBox li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .mainCateBox li:hover {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .mainCateBox li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .mainCateBox li.active {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .mainCateBox li.active a {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>


<div id="prdListCate">
    <ul class="mainCateBox">
        <li data-target="index"><a href="index.html">MAIN</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub01"><a href="sub01.html">SUB01</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub02"><a href="sub02.html">SUB02</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of trimming URL, so it will match data-target. You can check that it works.
so just replace

```
var url = window.location;
```

with

```
var url = window.location.split('&')[0];
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setLink = 'sub01.html&page=2';
    var url = setLink.split('&')[0];
    console.log(url);
    $('.mainCateBox li a[href="' + 'data-target' + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('.mainCateBox li a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .mainCateBox {
        position: relative;
    }

    .mainCateBox:after {
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }

    .mainCateBox li {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 180px;
        height: 34px;
        float: left;
        line-height: 34px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .mainCateBox li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .mainCateBox li:hover {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .mainCateBox li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .mainCateBox li.active {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .mainCateBox li.active a {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>


<div id="prdListCate">
    <ul class="mainCateBox">
        <li data-target="index"><a href="index.html">MAIN</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub01"><a href="sub01.html">SUB01</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub02"><a href="sub02.html">SUB02</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```